# Create a cocoa button that accepts keyboard input

Tags: cocoa, macos

Hey everyone, thanks for all your help so far, I've learned a whole lot in a short amount of time.

What I've done so far is to create a small calculator program and it works nicely.  To complete this version of it, what I'd like to do is make my "keys" on the calculator interface accept input from my keyboard presses.  So, for example, if I want to add 2 and 4, instead of clicking my "2" and "4" buttons, I can just press them on my numeric keypad instead.

I know it has something to do with giving my buttons focus but I can't figure out how to make them respond to keydown events.

I'm looking around on the apple developer documentation as well, so if I find the answers before you guys can then I'll try what I find out, and if it doesn't work I'll post with my progress.

Again, thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the key equivalent in interface builder. Click on the button in interface builder open the inspector and open it to the first tab. Under the first section there is a Key Equiv: and a gray box you can click on. Click on it and press the key you want to press it.

[image]

Comment: wow that's a lot easier than I thought it was going to be. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using interface builder, just set the "Key Equivalent" field to be your number.

[image: Button Attributes]

Comment: Thanks for your help, too! That's a great tip. I gave Justin the answer check because he answered first but also he doesn't have as much rep as you. hope you don't mind :)